# Fastest way of determining Threshold of Weak classifier (adaboost)

Tags: c++, adaboost

I am trying to implement a faster way of determining the threshold of my weak classifier. Currently I have a function that takes in a positive vector and a negative vector of values. Along with the associated weights of each sample. I then create N number of threshold I step through to determine which of these N thresholds are the best threshold for this weak classifier. I do this by looping through each sample and compare it to the threshold if it is incorrectly classified I add the weight of the samples to a error variable. The code can be seen below:

NOTE: the weights are normalized so they all sum up to 1. Also there is an equal number of positive and negative samples.

**INPUTS**: inp_pos is a 1000x1 vector of positive sample values ranging from 0 to 1. inp_neg is another 1000x1 vector of negative samples ranging from 0 to 1. weight_pos and weight_neg are another 1000x1 vector which are the weights associated with each sample. The sum of both of these vectors will be equal to 1. The final input N, which is the number of equal spaced thresholds we will be searching for to determine which weak classifier generates the smallest error.

**OUTPUTS**: The outputs are the threshold and parity. Parity tells us that if 0 then left of the threshold is positive. if parity is 1 then right of thee threshold is negative.

**How it Works**: we concatenate inp_pos and inp_neg together and then determine the min and max values. We take the max value subtract it from the min value, then divide it by our input N, and this gives us our threshold step. We then have a loop N that will loop through all of the possible thresholds. Then we have an innner loop that loops through the samples. If the inp_pos[k] is right of the threshold then the weight of weight_pos[k] is added to a tempError0 variable. And to cut down time and looping through the parity 1 - tempError0 will gives us tempError1, which is if the error if the parity is switched. We then store the smallest error, with the associated threshold and parity.

**Time Complexity**: if we generalize the number of samples of inp_pos to be an Mx1 vector and inp_neg is the same size. We will get a complexity that is O(N*M). Where a smaller N will make it faster but affect the performance.

**GOAL**: I would like to know if there is some way that I can make this faster without loss of performance. I don't know if there is a way I can sort these inp_pos and inp_neg vectors and determine a threshold based off of the sorted vectors. If I can how would I do that and is it faster?

```
float decideThres2(float &threshold, int &parity, vector<float> inp_pos, vector<float> inp_neg, vector<float> weight_pos, vector<float> weight_neg, int N){
//if parity is 0 positve decision is on the left
//if parity is 1 positive decision is on the right
//Threshold determine the threshold per sample
float error = 1.0;
float tempError0 = 0.0;
float tempError1 = 0.0;
vector<float> tempThresh;
float min, max;
//Concatenating inp_neg, inp_pos
tempThresh.resize(inp_pos.size() + inp_neg.size());                     // preallocate memory
tempThresh.insert(tempThresh.end(), inp_pos.begin(), inp_pos.end());
tempThresh.insert(tempThresh.end(), inp_neg.begin(), inp_neg.end());

//Finding the min and max values
max = *max_element(tempThresh.begin(), tempThresh.end());
min = *min_element(tempThresh.begin(), tempThresh.end());

float stepThrehold = (max - min) / N;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){                                //Looping through N equally Spaced thresholds
    //Parity loop
    //for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    tempError0 = 0;
    tempError1 = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < inp_pos.size(); k++){       //Comparing the threshold to positive and negative samples
        if (inp_pos[k] > stepThrehold*i)
            tempError0 += weight_pos[k];
        if (inp_neg[k] <= stepThrehold*i)
            tempError0 += weight_neg[k];
    }
    tempError1 = 1 - tempError0;
    if (tempError0 < error || tempError1 < error){
        if (tempError0 <= tempError1){
            error = tempError0;
            parity = 0;
            threshold = stepThrehold*i;
        }
        else{
            error = tempError1;
            parity = 1;
            threshold = stepThrehold*i;
        }
    }

}


return error;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: More information and clearer final goal please.

Comment: I'll try to edit it to make it more clear.